# Firebase Performance Monitoring showing 0 sessions

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-performance

I have added firebase performance monitoring following the documentation. There is data showing up but its saying 0 sessions and when viewing the sessions no cpu/memory data is showing up but it is saying that I need to update the SDK to see that information.

Comment: Same here. Have you found a solution?

Comment: @TalL no unfortunately. it did kind of start showing up but I changed nothing. I dont know if its a volume thing. or something specific because there isnt taht much session data thats come through

Comment: It looks like @Visu was right. All I needed was patience. The informations appears not immediately but after a certain number of data points are gathered.

Answer (score 3):

One of the possible issues is that there is a random sampling on different sessions that can captures such detailed metrics. May be that is causing this happen. Try generating more scenarios and you should be able to see some sessions with actual data.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/perf-mon/automatic?authuser=0#more-detail-trace-samples

Answer (score -1):

Please Check Your Firebase Remote Config